# Google sheet extract URL parameter strings

Tags: google-sheets

I want to extract "c=; t=; s=" values to columns, in delimited string with commas in Google sheet. The values could be repeated multiple times up to 10. C= are always only two capital letters

For example https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19bB5sI7t_awJH88xg5vtjD9qr0CKY79qcnsQxEE4jYA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @l'-'l  I put them in a google sheet now lol ... https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19bB5sI7t_awJH88xg5vtjD9qr0CKY79qcnsQxEE4jYA/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

B2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTJOIN(", ",1,IF(REGEXMATCH(SPLIT($A2,"&"),B$1&"="),REGEXEXTRACT(SPLIT($A2,"&"),"=(\w+)$"),)))
```

- SPLIT the string by `&`
- IF it matches any of the headers `t` or `c`(B1), then
- EXTRACT the corresponding string after  `=` and
- JOIN them back

Comment: @l'-'l Thank you this works very well.. , I modified slightly to allow hyphened tags to work =ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTJOIN(", ",1,IF(REGEXMATCH(SPLIT($N13,"&"),P$1&"="),REGEXEXTRACT(SPLIT($N13,"&"),"=('?\w[\w']*(?:-\w+)*'?)"),)))